# WRITE_ERROR_TO_CLIENT Error in apache

Tags: java, apache, weblogic

I am getting the below error. Env is Apache and WEblogic.

```
Write to the client failed: calling URL::close at line 847 of ap_proxy.cpp
Exception type [WRITE_ERROR_TO_CLIENT] raised at line 848 of ap_proxy.cpp
 request [/mywebservice?WSDL] did NOT process successfully
```

Comment: can anyone comment here please... ? Its an urgetn issue for me.

Comment: Any takers for this question. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

AFroz: I am getting the same error but in Weblogic10.3 and IIS plugin. Below are my finding and resolutions

Post my application was sending to IIS server

`POST <hostname/pagedetails> HTTP/1.0'`
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, */*
Referer: 
`User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;`.NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C)
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
Host: 
`<b>Content-Length: 38579</b>`
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
`Pragma: no-cache`
Cookie: `SMSESSION=

`JSESSIONID=0JppPKFpLXk8HMynBLDbBJPltLL70GvQ8Cyl56hhnXbjT7JbrgmR!847042037

Error recived

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2012 10:56:31 GMT
Set-Cookie: SMSESSION=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; path=/; domain=
Content-Type: text/html
```

```
ISAPI plug-in Error MessageMessage from the ISAPI plugin:
Internal Server failure, ISAPI plugin. Cannot continue.
Build date/time: Jan 31 2003
Change Number: 235118
```

When I have removed the below line from the post it gave us the correct response.
**Content-Length: 38579**
The server was able to process

Issue:
The error is due to the browser not sending the correct character count to the IIS server. 
Actual Size of the request header is 38597

Resolution:
As in Javascript we can't remove the Content-Length from the header
We need to do the changes in IIS side
ie
In InetMgr you need to Server Node -> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings and increase Buffer Setting.

Other Uri :

http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting

http://forums.iis.net/t/1174461.aspx

Tools used to find the post :
tcp_reflector

www.vulcanware.com/java_tcp_reflector/index.html

Comment: Completely different error. The OP's error is the server failing to write to the client. This error is the server succeeding in writing a 500 status to the client,. Read the question.